# how to remove outline just from click, not removing from keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, frontend, accessibility

I have a class in which I apply the `outline` on the click, and I would like to remove it only from the click and not from the keyboard navigation (tab), with keyboard navigation the `outline` should remain.

```
.po-radio-focus label {
  outline-color: var(--color-radio-group-border-color-focusable, var(--outline-color-focused));

  outline-width: var(--border-width-lg);
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alQWv.png)

Comment: Why not `:focus`?

Comment: this way i lose the outline when i navigate via keyboard

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what the CSS `:focus-visible` selector is for:

> This selector is useful to provide a different focus indicator based on the user's input modality (mouse vs. keyboard).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to remove the `outline` just from the click and not from the keyboard navigation.

```
  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target'])
  focusOut(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.radio.nativeElement, 'po-radio-focus')
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event.target'])
  onKeyup(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.radio.nativeElement, 'po-radio-focus');
  }

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event.target'])
  onKeydown(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.radio.nativeElement, 'po-radio-focus');
  }
```

Comment: The above solution is assuming that keyboard keys are the only way to focus an element with a need to display a focus outline. What about programmatically set focus?